# Responsive flexbox for mobile

Tags: html, css

This is how my desktop page looks: [desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk1Jo.png)

...and it should look like this on mobile: [Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfHxr.png)

This is my HTML/CSS for the desktop version, which is looking good.

```css
.skills {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #F25C05;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.skillsr {
  width: 45%;
  background-color: #F25C05;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.skillsh {
  width: 55%;
  background-color: #F25C05;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.skillsj {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #F25C05;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.skillsb {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #F25C05;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.montainer {
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
}

.sontainer {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
}

.zontainer {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 13px;
}

.fontainer {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2px;
}

.gontainer {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 6px;
}

.CSS {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  gap: 86px;
}
```

```html
<section class="aptitudini">
  <div class="aptitudini__container">
    <h2>Aptitudini</h2>
    <div class="CSS">CSS
      <div class="montainer">
        <div class="skills css">&nbsp </div>
      </div>
      <div class="RJS">ReactJS</div>
      <div class="montainer">
        <div class="skillsr">&nbsp </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="HTML">HTML
      <div class="sontainer">
        <div class="skillsh">&nbsp </div>
      </div>
      <div>&nbsp NodeJS</div>
      <div class="zontainer">
        <div class="skillsj">&nbsp </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="JAVA">JAVA
      <div class="gontainer">
        <div class="skillsj">&nbsp </div>
      </div>
      <div>&nbsp &nbsp Bootstrap</div>
      <div class="fontainer">
        <div class="skillsb">&nbsp </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

HTML and JAVA classes are the same with .CSS, with display:flex, paddings and gap.

What should I add in the @media to make it responsive?

Answer (score 0):

It cant look like the desktop because of the tiny screen.
flex is responsive and it acts like that.